# Was there an official name for the bomb detonated in the Manhattan Project

Tags: world-war-two, nuclear-weapons

In 1939 the Manhattan Project was started. The Manhattan project eventually gave us the precedents to the incredible and terrifying weapon known commonly as "a nuke" or "a nuclear bomb"

During the Manhattan Project a bomb was detonated in the Arizona deserts. That bomb is said to have started the nuclear weaponry phase. Was there an official name for that bomb, aside from "the Trinity test"? if so what was the name of the bomb. (similar to Little-boy and Fatman dropped on Nagasaki and Hiroshima)

Comment: Please check Wikipedia before asking to avoid having the question closed as trivial.

Comment: Last I checked, the Trinity site, situated on the White Sands Missile Range, was still in the state of New Mexico.

Comment: I looked for an hour on wikipedia but I couldn’t find the name of the bomb. They never specifically list it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the entry on the [Trinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_(nuclear_test)#The_Gadget) test:

> The test was of an implosion-design plutonium device, informally
>   nicknamed "The Gadget", of the same design as the Fat Man bomb later
>   detonated over Nagasaki, Japan, on August 9, 1945.

The name is quite fitting as you can see from this picture at [The Manhatten Project, an Interactive History](https://www.osti.gov/opennet/manhattan-project-history/Events/1945/trinity.htm)

[image]

see also:[Trinity Test -1945](https://www.atomicheritage.org/history/trinity-test-1945)

Comment: Wow! Thats insane!!! Thanks so much for your answer, I will be reading up on it with the links you provided.